# MySQL Query fails in my App, but succeeds in MySQL Command Line Tool

Tags: spring, mysql, jdbc

I am running this MySQL query against my db that contains a lot of customer data. the query is giant so I'll cut out parts. We're using 5.1.45-51-log Percona SQL Server which is a pretty common version of MySQL.

```
select distinct *  " +
               "from customer_contact_preferences prefs " +
...
               "join re_account_attribute uaa on uaa.account_id = ua.id " +
              "where ... " +
...
               "and uaa.attribute_key = 'R_GROUP' " +
               //"and uaa.attribute_value in ( ? ) " + //PROBLEM HERE
              "order by customer_contact_id)"
```

the argument to uaa.attribute value is '1','2',3'.

In the code, we use org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJDBCDaoSupport.update() to call this query.
When it is called in the code through Spring, it incorrectly returns 0 rows. When I substitute the args (4 people have checked that I did the substitution right), and run it on the mysql command line, the query correctly returns >5 rows. If I comment out the problem line, like i'm doing above, I get >5 and actually too many rows (that's why I need that constraint).

The table is described as follows:

```
| attribute_key      | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| attribute_value    | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
```

It is so we can store any kind of key/value pair, not restricted to varchar or ints.

Anyway, what is wrong with doing "IN " when you have a string or list of strings? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameterized `IN` clauses are supported by Spring JDBC templates only if you use named parameters instead of `?`s, see [12.7.3 Passing in lists of values for IN clause](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-in-clause). So, you need

```
getSimpleJdbcTemplate().update("... IN (:params) ...", 
    Collections.singletonMap("params", ...));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't bind a List or array to '?'.

You have to create a '?' for each item in the List or array in the SQL and then bind each one individually.

```
List<String> values = Arrays.asList(new String [] { "foo", "bar", "baz" });
StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
sql.append("SELECT * FROM X WHERE ID IN (");
for (int i = 0; i < values.length; ++i)
{
    sql.append('?');
    if (i != values.length-1))
        sql.append(',');
}
sql.append(")");
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql.toString());
for (int i = 0; i < values.length; ++i)
{
    ps.setString(i+1, values[i]);
}
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

Comment: Thanks this is great info. I need a spring compatible way, see solution below.